# how to fetch details from a file and store in a temporary file in shell script?

Tags: shell

I have a `config.txt` that has details like

```
DB_IP=10.10.1.120, DB_NAME=mysql
```

Then I created a file say `details.txt` with placeholders i.e

```
DB_ip_address=@@ip@@, DB_name=@@name@@
```

Now i need a temporary file that fetches details from `config.txt` and replaces placeholders that are there in `details.txt`. So my temp file should be

```
DB_ip_address=10.10.1.120 
DB_name=mysql
```

Comment: `please write shell script for this problem` Aha!

Comment: Add your email address, we'll write one and email it to you.

Comment: One clarification: Don't you need to replace the password?

Comment: I don't see how `DB_NAME`, `DB_name`, and `@@name@@` are related. What is the replacement logic?

Comment: I didn't know SO was an outsourcing agency.

Comment: config.txt is my source file, details.txt is something like Dummy file that gives the syntax for the original output file..

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
x=($(grep -Po "(?<=DB_IP=)(.+)(?=,)|(?<=DB_NAME=)(.+)" config.txt))  
y=($(grep -Eo "[a-zA-Z_]+=" details.txt))
echo $y$x > temp.txt
echo ${y[1]}${x[1]} >> temp.txt
```

Assuming that the order of DB_IP and DB_NAME is always same in both files.